# How can I change number format to decimals in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this counter and I need it to be in decimals (instead of having 150000000 I'd like to have 150.000.000,00 or at least 150.000.000).

I tried replace this:

```
step: function() {
    $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
}
```

with this:

```
formatter: function (value, options) {
    return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
}
```

but it didn't work. What can I do?

These are parts of my js and html interested by this:

```js
var a = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var oTop = $('#counter').offset().top - window.outerHeight/2;
  if (a == 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
      euro.className = "testo one column hide"
    $('.counter-value').each(function() {
        
      var $this = $(this),
          
        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
        
        
      $({
           
        countNum: $this.text()
          
      }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        },
                 

        {
          
          duration: 2000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {

            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
            //alert('finished');
          }

        });
    });
    a = 1;
  } else {
    euro.className = "testo one column show"
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="counter" class="two columns counter-value" data-count="150000000">
            
        </div>
```

Comment: You are doing math stuffs on a string. Try to use `parseFloat()` on `value` first

Answer (score 0):

toFixed is a good method, but it will only take care of the decimals at the end. To accomplish what you are describing you may want to use number.toLocaleString(). So your formatter would look like:

```
formatter: function(value, options) {
     return value.toLocaleString(options);
}
```

You can check out the toLocaleString options in the MDN docs below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Hope that helps!